# Adding default arguments to virtual methods

Tags: c++

In the following code, I would like to add new default argument 'z' to 'func' method without modifying subclasses. I get error C2259: 'CTest' : cannot instantiate abstract class error.

Is there anyway to do this without modifying all subclasses?

```
class ITest
{
public:
    virtual void func(int x, int y, char c, int z = 1) = 0;
};

class CTest : public ITest
{
public:
    void func(int x, int y, char c)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not directly possible. The existing classes don't know of the `z` parameter, so can't use it. If you want to provide some new subclasses whose clients will be aware of the `z` and be able to use it, you can do this:

```
class ITest
{
public:
    virtual void func(int x, int y, char c) = 0;
    virtual void func(int x, int y, char c, int z)
    { func(x, y, c); }
};
```

This way, old classes work just as before, as will clients who call the 3-parameter version. You're also giving the option of new subclasses using `z` and new clients using the 4-parameter version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your `func()` method in subclass in order to make it match the one from parent class. Either way, you'll get this error: `cannot instantiate abstract class error`.

Answer (score -1):

You could add private data and initialize it as 1

```
class ITest
{
public:
    ITest(): z(1) {} 
    virtual void func(int x, int y, char c) = 0;
private:
    int z;
};
```

Comment: @LenHolgate: Agreed. Sorry about that. I misunderstood the meaning of int z = 1 and didn't check it before posting.